# In SAPUI5, they provide samples for codes. How to actually use those?

Tags: sapui5

I just started using SAPUI5 and I am actually curious on how the samples work.

For example:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout/sample/sap.f.sample.FlexibleColumnLayoutColumnResize

I downloaded it and opened using Atom IDE. However, I don`t see any mock data or .json.

Is that on purpose? I was actually expecting to see the code for the sample, with the sample data.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data gets loaded from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/f/demokit/sample/FlexibleColumnLayoutColumnResize/webapp/data/sections.json

see line 21 in Component.js: `var oProductsModel = new JSONModel("./data/sections.json");`

You can find details on how to set up a JSON model in [Step 7 of SAPUI5 Walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/70ef981d350a495b940640801701c409) - a tutorial with all major UI5 development paradigms.